# Translate this curl to Python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, header, translate

I was hoping someone can help me translate this curl request into the syntax using Python requests library. This API is supposed to provide me with a list of tickets . I am unfamiliar making a request with headers and an API key in Python so I would appreciate the help. Thank you. I was also getting a 403 Status code when trying to use the base URI.

curl request - changed sensative information.

```
curl -X POST \
  --url 'https://api.myapi.io/v2/apps/mine/xxx123/data/ticket/search' \
  -H 'x-api-key: myapiKEY123'\
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
  "startDate": "2021-03-01",
  "endDate": "2021-04-12"
}'
```

python code currently

```
import json
import requests

API_KEY = "myapiKEY123"
client_ID = 'xxx123'
url = '/v2/apps/mine/' + client_ID + '/data/ticket/search'
params = dict(key=API_KEY, lang='en-es')

requestObject = requests.get(
    url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(requestObject.status_code, requestObject.reason)
```

Current Error Message:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/v2/apps/mine/xxx123/data/ticket/search': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///v2/apps/mine/xxx123/data/ticket/search?
```

Comment: check this out: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a schema (http/https) on your URL, which is also not a complete URL:

```
import requests

api_key = "myapiKEY123"
client_id = 'xxx123'
url = f'https://api.myapi.io/v2/apps/mine/{client_id}/data/ticket/search'

headers = {
    'x-api-key': api_key,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}
data = {
    'startDate': '2021-03-01',
    'endDate': '2021-04-12',
}

response = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=10)

response.raise_for_status()
```

Then either print the response as JSON (if they're responding with JSON, which is probable) like `response.json()` or as text `response.text`. The `response.raise_for_status()` will check if the status code indicated a failure (e.g. the [response code was a 400-599](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response.raise_for_status)) and raise an exception with the status code and the error.

You're also not passing the API key in the format the curl is suggesting, which I fixed above. I also added a timeout, because note that the requests library does not have a timeout by default, so if the server misbehaves the connection will block forever which is not good.

I also doubt you're supposed to be passing the start and end date as query parameters rather than as data in the body of the request, so I've made that update as well. Using `params` would result in a request that looked like this:

```
https://api.myapi.io/v2/apps/mine/{client_ID}/data/ticket/search?startDate=2021-03-01&endDate=2021-04-12
```

When what the curl (and my above example) is doing is passing those values as JSON in the POST request body.

`requests.get()` is going to return a `requests.Response` object, so it's also a bit nonsensical to assign it to a variable called `requestObject`.

Review the following docs:

- [Post Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)
- [Passing parameters in URLS](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)
- [Custom Headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)
- [Timeouts](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)
- [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions)

It's not a functional problem in your code, but [by convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), function and variable names should be lowercase in Python and use underscores to separate terms, not camel case. E.g. response_object rather than responseObject, api_key rather than API_KEY, and client_id rather than client_ID. Again, it doesn't make your code not work, it's just convention. You can ignore it, but I wanted to point it out at least.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your immediate error, the url you are passing into the requests function is not complete. The message you get shows that the url starts with `/v2`, while it needs to have the complete url, that is, starting `https://`.

For your header question, the headers is a simple dictionary of key/value pairs, along the lines of:

```py
headers = {"x-api-key": "myapiKEY123", }
```

From there, you are passing it into the `requests.get` function correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that silly first mistake. Upon fixing my headers, I still receive a 403 error. Do you believe anything else may be incorrect in my code?

Comment: 403 normally indicates your token is incorrect. I do not know what this bit of code is doing: `params = dict(key=API_KEY, lang='en-es')` but you likely don't need it, see @dephekt's answer